# How to pull partition key from HttpTrigger route with DocumentDb?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm attempting to write a function that pulls all documents based on a partition key, executed via an HttpTrigger with a REST-like route. The documentation uses the `{propertyName}` syntax, but uses a Queue Trigger that passes a POCO.

My route is:
`/api/accounts/{accountId}/messages`

The function looks like the following:

```
[FunctionName("getAllMessages")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(Route = "accounts/{accountId}/messages")]HttpRequestMessage req,
    string accountId,
    [DocumentDb(PartitionKey = "{accountId}"]IEnumerable<Message> messages
) {
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, messages);
}
```

This returns all messages regardless of partition key. Debugging verifies that the `accountId` argument is being picked up correctly.

Using `DocumentClient` instead of the input binding returns the correct set of messages (culls anything that doesn't match the account id).

```
var query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery(
    /* ... */,
    new FeedOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(accountId) }
);

return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, query.ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

> This returns all messages regardless of partition key. Debugging verifies that the accountId argument is being picked up correctly.

I have tested your code, I also get the same result. It seems that the partition key don’t work. But we could get the value of accountId. If you really want to get
the specific partition key messages, I suggest you could use `SqlQuery = "select * from c where c.accountId={accountId}"` in  **DocumentDB** attribute. Besides, you could also post a question about this bug in github.

Comment: Added an github issue to track:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/368